# A simple AND query with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a simple query for two specified fields, and the manual and google is proving to be of little help. Example below should make it pretty clear what I want to do.

```
{
  "query": {
      "and": {
        "term": {
          "name.family_name": "daniel",
          "name.given_name": "tyrone"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

As a bonus question, why does it find "Daniel Tyrone" with "daniel", but NOT if I search for "Daniel". It behaves like a realy weird anti case sensitive search.

Answer (score 23):

Edit: Updated, sorry.  You need a separate `Term` object for each field, inside of a Bool query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
          {
           "term": {
             "name.family_name": "daniel"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "name.given_name": "tyrone"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Term queries are not analyzed by ElasticSearch, which makes them case sensitive.  A Term query says to ES "*look for this exact token inside your index, including case and punctuation*".

If you want case insensitivity, you could add a keyword + lowercase filter to your analyzer.  Alternatively, you could use a query that analyzes your text at query time (like a `Match` query)

Edit2: You could also use And or Bool filters too.

Comment: You misunderstood my case sensitive question, I am saying it is behaving like an INVERSE case sensitive search, it does NOT find "Daniel" when I search with "Daniel"

Comment: The query example you gave, gives me an error > http://pastium.org/view/c0efa58b6b7689bfff5a9f480c01ed01

Comment: Gah, sorry about that.  I should never answer questions on SO before coffee.  I was thinking the And filter, when in reality ES only has the Bool query.  You can also use the Bool or And filter depending on your use-case.

Comment: Re: case sensitivity...how do you have your analyzer set up?  The same points apply - Term is only searching for the exact token stored inside the index.  You might have an analyzer that is lowercasing your text before storing?

Comment: I have not really set up any analyzers. It is just using default

Comment: In that case, the default analyzer is the [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-analyzer.html), which includes a lowercase filter.  That's why you have this case sensitivity problem :)

Comment: and a lowercase filter lowercases the values but not the queries? I fail to see how this could ever be useful.

Comment: The Term query is not_analyzed, which means it isn't run through the fields analyzer.  Other queries, such as Match query, will process the query text with the analyzer and appropriately lowercase.  There are definitely valid use-cases for a Term query - just not yours.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for at least multiple text comparisons on the same field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.given_name": {
        "query": "daniel tyrone",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
```

And I found this for multiple fields, is this the correct way?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [        
        {
          "match": {
            "name.formatted": {
              "query": "daniel tyrone",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "display_name": "tyrone"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, your second query will work (assuming you want 'daniel tyrone' to be analyzed by the analyzers set on the doc field).

Comment: If you're not sure about the answer, you should not post it as an answer, you can always add it as a comment to your initial question

Comment: Finally I've found this! What does operator in your first query do? Am I right, that it will try to find words combination for given_name? In other words given_name should looks like 'daniel tyrone" not just daniel or tyrone?

Answer (score 0):

If composing the json with PHP, these 2 examples worked for me.

$activeFilters is just a comma separated string like: 'attractions, limpopo'

```
$articles = Article::searchByQuery(array(
        'match' => array(
            'cf_categories' => array(
                'query' => $activeFilters,
                'operator' =>'and'
            )
        )
    ));

    // The below code is also working 100%
    // Using Query String https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-query-filter.html
    // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
    /* $articles = Article::searchByQuery(array(
        'query_string' => array(
            'query' => 'cf_categories:attractions AND cf_categories:limpopo'
        )
    )); */
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `minimum_should_match` is set to `2` since the number of parameters for the `AND` query are `2`.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
                {"term": { "name.family_name": "daniel"}},
                {"term": { "name.given_name": "tyrone" }}
            ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 2

        }
    }
}
```