# Elasticsearch with AND query in DSL

Tags: elasticsearch

this drives me crazy. I have no clue why this elastic search do not return me value.
I put values with this:

```
PUT /customer/person-test/1?pretty
{
  "name": "John Doe",
   "personId": 153,
   "houseHoldId": 6191136,
   "quarter": "2016_Q1"
}

PUT /customer/person-test/2?pretty
{
  "name": "John Doe",
   "personId": 153,
   "houseHoldId": 6191136,
   "quarter": "2016_Q2"
}
```

and when I query like this, it do not returns me value:

```
GET /customer/person-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
          {
           "term": {
             "name": "John Doe"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "quarter": "2016_Q1"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

this query i copied from [A simple AND query with Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476943/a-simple-and-query-with-elasticsearch)

I just want to get the person with "John Doe" AND "2016_Q1", why this did not work?

Comment: What are the mappings of fields `quarteer` and ` name`? Can you also let us know hat ES version are you using?

Comment: If you are running ES 5.x version then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43427184/5936696) answer may help you!

Comment: the ES is 5.3.0 ,I just download from the official site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `match` instead of `term` :

```
GET /customer/person-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
          {
           "match": {
             "name": "John Doe"
           }
         },
         {
           "match": {
             "quarter": "2016_Q1"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

**Explanation**

> [Why doesn’t the term query match my document ?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)
>
> String fields can be of type text (treated as full text, like the body
>   of an email), or keyword (treated as exact values, like an email
>   address or a zip code). Exact values (like numbers, dates, and
>   keywords) have the exact value specified in the field added to the
>   inverted index in order to make them searchable.
>
> However, text fields are analyzed. This means that their values are
>   first passed through an analyzer to produce a list of terms, which are
>   then added to the inverted index.
>
> There are many ways to analyze text: the default standard analyzer
>   drops most punctuation, breaks up text into individual words, and
>   lower cases them. For instance, the standard analyzer would turn the
>   string “Quick Brown Fox!” into the terms [quick, brown, fox].
>
> This analysis process makes it possible to search for individual words
>   within a big block of full text.
>
> The term query looks for the exact term in the field’s inverted
>   index — it doesn’t know anything about the field’s analyzer. This
>   makes it useful for looking up values in keyword fields, or in numeric
>   or date fields. When querying full text fields, use the match query
>   instead, which understands how the field has been analyzed.
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

its not working because of u r using default standard analyzer [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer) for 'name' and 'quarter' .

You have two more options :-

1)change mapping :-

```
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  "quarter": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
```

2)try this , lowercase your value since by default standard analyzer use Lower Case Token Filter  :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
          {
           "term": {
             "name": "john_doe"
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "quarter": "2016_q1"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your second option will not work as `standard` analyzer tokenize `john doe` and store it in inverted index as two tokens `john` and `doe` where as `term` query will look for exact term `john doe` which will not found in inverted index.

Comment: Yes .You are right .It will work for one token only .